# Android phones that don't require a battery to run properly

Tags: battery, hardware

My Android phone apparently requires a battery in order to function.  If I take out the battery before boot, it shows an empty battery with a question mark on it and refuses to boot no matter how I press the power button.  If I pull the battery during the boot process it boots up just fine, but as soon as it finishes booting I get a dialog box telling me the battery isn't present and it automatically starts the shutdown process.  If I pull the battery after boot is completely finished, it instantly reboots as if I pressed shift+alt+del on my slide-out keyboard.

Is this standard Android behavior, or is this something unique to my phone?  If I ever replace my phone in the future I have a list of required features, and being able to run without a battery is one of them.  So, I need to know if this is going to restrict my options.

Comment: I've had ancient HTC Dream/HTC G1 and it run flawlessly without the battery. But the newer HTC DesireZ doesn't and neither does any other phone I've seen (but that's not much). I've no idea if running without battery is phone-dependent or is it something removed from android after some version, but from logical POV it looks to me as a hardware feature and not software one.